# Gatling + graphite multiple points for same scenario

Tags: graphite, gatling

I'm trying to render the result of my gatling scenario in graphite, but I have a problem. For the same scenario two points are generated in graphite for the "AllRequests" or I only want one. (Look below)

[image: Graphite render of my gatling scenario]

In this image I just executed my scenario twice and I had 4 points generated.
Here's my gatling configuration :

```
gatling {
  data {
    writers = "console, file, graphite"
    reader = file

    graphite {
      host = "thisismy.host"
      port = 2003
      #light = true              # only send the all* stats
      protocol = "tcp"           # The protocol used to send data to Carbon (currently supported : "tcp", "udp")
      #rootPathPrefix = "scenario" # The common prefix of all metrics sent to Graphite
      bufferSize = 8192         # GraphiteDataWriter's internal data buffer size, in bytes
      # writeInterval = 1         # GraphiteDataWriter's write interval, in seconds
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix that ? 
Thanks

## Edit

Here's my simulation (really simple) :

```
val scn = scenario("Auto generated scenario")
    .exec(CheckAvailability.checkAvailability)
    .exec(concatRequests)
    .exec(session => {
      responses = session.attributes
      session
    })

  setUp(
    scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
  )
```

Where concatRequests is a list of ChainBuilder.

Comment: Can you share your simulation please ?

Comment: Do you run one single Gatling instance, or two of them?

Comment: @StephaneLandelle Just one.

Comment: @PierreDAL-PRA I added my simulation to the question

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is simply some stats you do not want to track in your Graphite dashboard, or requests that you don't want to see reported.

I see two solutions:

- Either modify your dashboard to be more selective on the request that you want to plot : along with the `AllRequests`, you can have detailed metrics per request name.
- Make the unnecesarily reported requests `silent` : http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.6/http/http_request.html#silencing

Comment: I don't want to filter my requests, I want an average of the responses of all the requests sent, so I use the AllRequest report. I just don't get why it's creating more than one point in the graphite report. Sometimes it creates two or three points for the same simulation and that's totally random.

Comment: I tried to silent some useless requests but it doesn't change anything. it seems when the scenario last more than 10 seconds it creates more points. (one every 10 seconds)

Comment: Well, the whole point of using Graphite is to monitor your results in real-time, so yes, Gatling sends regularly data to Graphite.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood how the AllRequests work. I thought AllRequests was grouping the requests by **scenarios** or it's not, it groups requests by **time**. And because some requests starts ten second later it creates a second point.